# DateTime Ruby How to format correctly

Tags: ruby, loops, date, require

My project is supposed to fetch specific values from multiple hashes a put those values in a text file. Ideally what I need my code to do is to have every date for the employees be seven days apart, so the text file would look something like this:

```
"Rachel Thorndike
2017-10-09-T04:29:46-05:00
Stacie Smith
2017-10-16-T04:29:46-05:00"
```

What this is supposed to do is fetch employee's names and put the time of their "handoff" on the line under them. I looked online and found the DateTime that Ruby features but it looks like whatever I do isn't working. My code is this:

```
require 'date'
jsonUser["users"].each do |user|
  somefile.puts user["user"]["summary"]
  print 'Handoff Date + Time: '
  parsed = DateTime.strptime(jsonUser["start"], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
  utc = parsed.next_day(7).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
  puts utc
end
```

But terminal returns this code with an error `'strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)`. Would anybody help me get this code to work the way I want to? Anything that points me to the right direction? With explanations, if it isn't too much.

Thank you so much!

**Update**
I was able to get the iso8601 to appear under their name. My new code is 
require 'date'

```
jsonUser["users"].each do |user|
 somefile.puts user["user"]["summary"]
   print 'Handoff Date + Time: '
   parsed = DateTime.iso8601(jsonUser["start"])
   utc = parsed.next_day(7).iso8601
   somefile.puts utc
end
```

**BUT** the `.next_day` method isn't increasing by 7 days that I want too. Thought? I have only got one value that is appearing and that is going under every line. Its the value of `jsonUser["start"]` + 7 days...so `2017-

10-16T04:29:46-05:00`

This is what `parse.next_day(7)` gives me.

```
"Sr Chid
Handoff Date + Time: 2017-10-16T04:29:46-05:00
Ash A 
Handoff Date + Time: 2017-10-16T04:29:46-05:00
Ven D
Handoff Date + Time: 2017-10-16T04:29:46-05:00
Abhi S
Handoff Date + Time: 2017-10-16T04:29:46-05:00"
```

The value of `jsonUser["start"]` is `2017-10-09T04:29:46-05:00` so the good thing is that it did increase by 7 but it only did it once.

**Update for Amadan**

```
require 'date'
  date = DateTime.iso8601(jsonUser["start"])
  jsonUser["users"].each do |user|
    if user["user"]["self"] == nil
      nil
    else
      somefile.puts user["user"]["summary"].gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize).gsub(/[.]/, ' ')
      somefile.print 'Handoff Date + Time: '
      date = date.next_day(7)
      somefile.puts date.iso8061
    end
  end
```

Comment: I just found out that I should change the `.strptime` to `.iso8601`. Good choice?

Comment: As well as change `.strftime` to `.iso8601`

Comment: Yes ISO 8601 is the format I want and is the value of the key `jsonUser["start"]`. I have no idea what you mean by DateTime calling `next_day(7)` in which you asked. The only thing it is returning is the value for `jsonUser["start"]` right after the name. And I'm not running rails but `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]`

Comment: I'll update it. Give me a sec..

Comment: Its updated....

Comment: Why would `utc` change if `jsonUser["start"]` does not change? The loop variable is `user`, not `jsonUser`. Start by `date = DateTime.iso8601(jsonUser["start"])` _outside_ of the loop, then `somefile.puts date.iso8861; date = date.next_day(7)` inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry. Would I put that code at a line before `end`?

Comment: Ok this is what happen Amadan. `undefined method iso8061 for #<DateTime:0x007fba758312d8> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: I'll update it for you to see what I put

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION.

Comment: You were almost there Amadan. Instead of ending it with `somefile.puts date.iso8601` as the ending...You were supposed to take out the `iso8601`

Comment: But do you know why? Is it because you already defined it in the date?